# How to runtime disable xDebug's var_dump and errors prettify?

Tags: php, xdebug

I sometimes prefer to use

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

Do not mess around with HTML. However, whenever an error occurs, or when I use `var_dump()`, it would issue a large HTML block to prettify the output. While it's great in HTML context, I would like to disable it when I work in text/plain.

Is it possible to do? Runtime disable of the prettify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDebug will show you an error if PHP HTML errors are enabled. You can do one of the following

1. You can disable php errors from displayed.

   `ini_set('display_errors', 0)`
2. Or you can change `html_errors = On` setting of php.ini for xdebug to `html_errors = Off'`

   `ini_set('html_errors', 'off')`

But you should know, you cannot prevent PARSE errors from appearing using `ini_set()`.

Comment: I don't want the errors gone, I want them displayed, but in text/plain, instead of illegible HTML that doesn't get parsed by the browser.

Comment: @ObitoUchiha so I recommend using the second option